# Lost on introductory abstract algebra proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functions

I'm fairly lost on where to begin this proof and would like direction to resources that might help me understand what I'm meant to show.

The proof is:

Prove that If $m|n$, then $\pi_{m,n}: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ is well-defined.

---

I know that $m|n$ means that $n=m*k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that if $m|n$, then $\pi_{m,n} ([a]_n)=[a]_m$

And I know that for a function $f:X \to Y$ to be well-defined I must prove that:

1.) 
f is a relation from X to Y
f⊆X×Y

2.)
The domain of f
is X, every element in X is related to some element of Y ∀x∈X,∃y∈Y:(x,y)∈f

3.)
No element of X
is related to more than one element of Y ∀x∈X,∀y1,y2∈Y:(x,y1),(x,y2)∈f⟹y1=y2

I'm not sure how these facts/properties relate to the requested proof and any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated. I think the Chinese Remainder Theorem may be involved, but that may just be a stab in the dark on my part.

Comment: You should not delete the body of your question. This hurts future students who may have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Write $a+n\mathbb{Z}$ for the element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ corresponding to the equivalence class of integers modulo $n$ which contains $a$. The function $\pi_{n,m}$ in question is defined by $$\pi_{n,m}(a+n\mathbb{Z})=a+m\mathbb{Z}\qquad \mbox{ for all } a\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
Recall that a function associates each member of the domain to precisely one member of the codomain. Therefore, we say that $\pi_{n,m}$ is *well-defined* if $\pi_{n,m}(a+n\mathbb{Z})=\pi_{n,m}(b+n\mathbb{Z})$ whenever $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $a+n\mathbb{Z}=b+n\mathbb{Z}$.

In other words, the question is asking you to show that if $m\mid n$ and $a\equiv b\mod n$, then $a\equiv b\mod m$.

Answer (score 0):

What you have stated is definition of a function. To check if $f$ is well-defined you need to ensure that regardless of the representative used for the input, the output will remain the same. Said differently, if $x_1,x_2$ are two representatives of the same object in the domain (so $x_1=x_2$), then for well-definedness you need to ensure that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

To give you an example, let $f:\mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ be given by $f([x]_8)=[x]_{12}$. Is this well-defined? Observe that $[0]_8=[8]_8$  but $f([0]_8)=[0]_{12}$ and $f([8]_8)=[8]_{12}$ are not the same outputs. Hence the function is NOT well-defined.

In your question with $\pi_{m,n}([x]_{n})=[x]_{m}$. Let $[x]_n=[y]_n$, then $ x\equiv y \pmod{n}$. Now we are given that $m | n$, so $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$ (by transitivity--$m$ divides $n$ and $n$ divides $x-y$, so $m$ divides $x-y$). But this also implies,that $[x]_m=[y]_m$, which means $$\pi_{m,n}([x]_{n})=\pi_{m,n}[y]_{n}.$$
Hence well-defined.